# How do i add .pdb file associated with a lib file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

How do i add .pdb file associated with a lib file?

I am importing a  .lib file in a C++ project. When I build it i get an error saying that vc90.pdb does not contains the debug information.
I have the pdb file associated with the library. how can i add it to my current project.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We just have the pdb file sitting in the same directory as the .lib file with the same name (ie. foo.lib and foo.pdb) and the compiler appears to pick that up automatically. We don't explicitly point anything at the .pdb files.

I think vc90.pdb is VS2008's fallback if it can't find one with the same name.

Comment: i have a pdb file called communicator.pdb with communicator.lib
still it wont take it

Comment: Did you set the name of the .pdb file in the project that built the .lib file, or are you renaming it after the fact? It may be that the .lib file carries the name of the .pdb in it?